# 2 Page view in Preview shows the right page on the left and left page on the right?

Tags: macos, pdf, osx-leopard, preview, pdf-reader

I have a pdf that I am reading in Preview and I would like to view it in 2 page mode as many pages reference illustrations on the next page. However, when I enable 2 page mode, the left page is put on the right and the previous right page is put on the left. Is there any way to fix this and view the 2 pages that would go with one another in a physical copy of the book?

Answer (score 5):

A workaround would be to use [**Skim.app**](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/), an open source PDF reader replacement. Don't worry, it's very lightweight.

Open the PDF, from the *PDF* menu, select *PDF Display → Two Pages Continuous*. Now, the default view is:

[image: like this]

… which is called "Book Mode". Preview.app doesn't allow us to change this option. In Skim.app, we can disable *Book Mode* from the *PDF Display* menu:

[image: like shown here]

So, either way, you'll be able to fix the left/right issue for any PDF. Preview.app doesn't seem to make this "Book Mode" selectable, even though it kind-of uses the same menu as Skim and I found a hint that it actually used to have it. I can't see it on OS X 10.6.8 though.

Answer (score 4):

There are two workarounds that involve editing the PDF file in Preview: inserting a blank page after the first page, or deleting the first page.

### Insert a blank page

Insert a blank page right after the first page, with the menu item *Edit → Insert → Blank Page*:

[image: page 1 selected]

[image: menu item Edit → Insert → Blank Page]

The blank page will be inserted after the current page, and will be the same size as the current page.

[image: after inserting blank page]

If needed, you can drag the blank page’s thumbnail to change its ordering in the document.

### Delete the first page

Choose View → Thumbnails from the menu.

[image: menu item View → Thumbnails]

The first page will already be selected.

[image: page 1 selected]

Hit <kbd>delete</kbd>.

[image: after deleting first page]

---

After either of these workarounds, pages will be displayed on the correct side of the window:

[image: fixed two-page view]

If you don’t want the added blank page or missing first page to be permanent, make sure to undo the change you made (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>) before closing and saving the document.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to delete the first page of the pdf in Preview.app. Or insert a page before the first page.